# Wxpython save is not working in Windows7

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets

I need to save a text file in my editor  this is the code for saving the file  but the code is not working in Windows 7
my code is

```
def OnSaveFile(self, event):
        if self.last_name_saved:

            try:
                file = open(self.last_name_saved, 'w')
                text = self.text.GetValue()
                file.write(text.encode('utf-8'))
                file.close()
                self.statusbar.SetStatusText(os.path.basename(self.last_name_saved) + ' saved', 0)
                self.SetTitle(os.path.basename(self.last_name_saved))
                self.modify = False
                self.statusbar.SetStatusText('', 1)

            except IOError, error:
                dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, 'Error saving file\n' + str(error))
                dlg.ShowModal()
        else:
            self.OnSaveAsFile(event)
```

This is my error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\EZHUTHANI_WIN\ezhuthani\beditor.py", line 301, in OnSaveFile
self.OnSaveAsFile(event)
File "F:\EZHUTHANI_WIN\ezhuthani\beditor.py", line 308, in OnSaveAsFile
if save_dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\_windows.py", line 711, in ShowModal
return _windows_.Dialog_ShowModal(*args, **kwargs)
```

This is the module for saving file in the program

```
def OnSaveAsFile(self, event):
        wcd='All files(*)|*|Editor files (*.ef)|*.ef|'
        dir = os.getcwd()
        save_dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, message='Save file as...', defaultDir=dir, defaultFile='',
                        wildcard=wcd, style=wx.SAVE | wx.OVERWRITE_PROMPT)
        if save_dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            path = save_dlg.GetPath()

            try:
                file = open(path, 'w')
                text = self.text.GetValue()
                file.write(text.encode('utf-8'))
                file.close()
                self.last_name_saved = os.path.basename(path)
                self.statusbar.SetStatusText(self.last_name_saved + ' saved', 0)
                self.modify = False
                self.statusbar.SetStatusText('', 1)
                self.SetTitle(window_title + path)
            except IOError, error:
                dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, 'Error saving file\n' + str(error))
                dlg.ShowModal()
        save_dlg.Destroy()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [wxPython file dialog error: missing "|" in the wildcard string!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950454/wxpython-file-dialog-error-missing-in-the-wildcard-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the wild card in the OnSaveAsFile() function,

change it to something like,

```
wcd='Text files(*.txt)|*.txt|Plain Text files (*.txt)|*.txt'
```